# Uploading to s3 via aws javascript sdk does not trigger lambda function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers

I'm uploading to my s3 bucket like so:

```
export async function UploadToS3(
  file: File,
  metadata: { "x-amz-meta-listing-id": string }
) {
  try {
    const listingId = metadata["x-amz-meta-listing-id"];
    const params: AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest = {
      ACL: "public-read",
      Body: file,
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: `listings/${listingId}.mp4`,
      Metadata: metadata,
    };
    const response = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    return {
      success: true,
      url: response.Location,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return {
      success: false,
      url: null,
    };
  }
}
```

The videos do end up being uploaded successfully:
[image]

In my `CloudWatch` logs, there is no attempt of triggering my `Lambda` function. I have tested an event in the AWS Console and it works, as well as manually uploading a file works. However adding it from my app does not trigger it.

My `trigger` looks like this:

```
Bucket arn: arn:aws:s3:::myprojectname-uk
Event type: s3:ObjectCreated:*
Notification name: 4f1d0abd-0294-4be6-b671-1e6bd7354c46
Prefix: listings/
Service principal: s3.amazonaws.com
Source account: 823446109543
Statement ID: lambda-c241c442-d944-4e38-9172-92062b79bab9
Suffix: .mp4
```

My `role` document for the lambda function is like so:

```
{
  "sdkResponseMetadata": null,
  "sdkHttpMetadata": null,
  "partial": false,
  "permissionsBoundary": null,
  "policies": [
    {
      "arn": null,
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": null,
      "name": "LambdaToS3",
      "type": "inline"
    },
    {
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": "ANPAJNCQGXC42545SKXIK",
      "name": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
      "type": "managed"
    }
  ],
  "resources": {
    "s3": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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",
        "name": "Amazon S3"
      },
      "statements": [
        {
          "action": "s3:PutObject",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "s3",
          "source": {
            "index": "VisualEditor0",
            "policyName": "LambdaToS3",
            "policyType": "inline"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "s3:GetObject",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "s3",
          "source": {
            "index": "VisualEditor0",
            "policyName": "LambdaToS3",
            "policyType": "inline"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "logs": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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",
        "name": "Amazon CloudWatch Logs"
      },
      "statements": [
        {
          "action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        },
        {
          "action": "logs:PutLogEvents",
          "effect": "Allow",
          "resource": "*",
          "service": "logs",
          "source": {
            "index": "0",
            "policyName": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
            "policyType": "managed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "roleName": "LambdaAccessS3",
  "trustedEntities": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```